# How to stop a block of code from happening once an incorrect key is pressed

Tags: python, if-statement, random, tkinter, shuffle

So I have this block of code if the user types what's on screen correctly.

```
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discomobobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]
wordcount = 0
maxwords = 12        
skips = 0

def nextWord():
        global score
        global wordcount
        global skips
        global maxwords
        global name
        global high_score

        entry.focus_set()

        if entry.get().lower() == words[1].lower():
            score += 1
            wordcount += 1
            wordcounter.config(text="Words: " + str(wordcount))
```

And I'd like to know how to stop this block of code from running if they don't type what's on the screen:

```
        for i in range(maxwords):
            entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            random.shuffle(words)
            label.config(text=str(words[1]))
            scoreLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(score)+ "s")
```

It continues even if they don't type it correctly because of:

```
def startGame(event):
    nextWord()

root.bind("<Return>", startGame)
```

I currently have this:

```
    elif entry.get().lower() != words[1].lower():
            wronglabel.config(text="WRONG!")
            time.sleep(0.6)
            wronglabel.delete(0, tkinter.END)
```

What this currently does is make

```
wronglabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))
wronglabel.pack()
```

Say wrong but I'd like to know how to make it not randomly shuffle and get items from the list if they user does not enter the correct word.
Thanks.

All together, it makes this:(posting only relevant code):

```
#Add words to this list to include them in the game
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discombobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]
wordcount = 0
maxwords = [len(words)]       

def nextWord():
        global score
        global wordcount
        global maxwords
        global name
        global high_score

        entry.focus_set()

        if entry.get().lower() == words[1].lower():
            score += 1
            wordcount += 1
            wordcounter.config(text="Words: " + str(wordcount))

        elif entry.get().lower() != words[1].lower():
                wronglabel.config(text="WRONG!")

        for i in words[len(maxwords)]:
            entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            random.shuffle(words)
            label.config(text=str(words[1]))
            scoreLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(score)+ "s")

def startGame(event):
    nextWord()

wronglabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))
wronglabel.pack()
```

(I have edited some minor things in the code to solve another problem)

Comment: Consider posting your entire script, it's unlikely anyone wants to try and piece it all together.

Answer (score 0):

I may just not be understanding this correctly, but can't you move the for loop inside the if statement like so?

```
if entry.get().lower() == words[1].lower():
    score += 1
    wordcount += 1
    wordcounter.config(text="Words: " + str(wordcount))

    for i in words[len(maxwords)]:
        entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        random.shuffle(words)
        label.config(text=str(words[1]))
        scoreLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(score)+ "s")
```

Comment: I've tried that but then it won't display the randomly shuffled word. This is the code I use to display the word and I wanted to know how to sort of, rearrange it so it could work.

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand what you want the for loop to do. It seems strange to repeat that code for X amount of times when it only needs to be done once. Although it is only occurring once because `maxwords = [len(words)]` is a list with a single value `len(maxwords)` will then return 1 and so `for i in words[len(maxwords)]:` i = the word at index 1 every time. But you're not even using i in the loop. So I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I've already fixed this issue and forgot to close the question. What I did up there is completely wrong anyways but thanks for trying to help.